Trying to get a unique list of values from a dictionary
I've got a dictionary that has a structure similar to:
{
    'id': 16, 
    'name': 'something', 
    'client': 'client1', 
}, 
{
    'id': 17, 
    'name': 'something', 
    'client': 'client2', 
},
{
    'id': 18, 
    'name': 'something-else', 
    'client': 'client3', 
}

I can iterate through my dicts in my templates but I'm trying to get the unique values of name in this case.  I've tried a couple different options such as:
{% for name in data | unique %}

or
{% for name in data.name | unique %}

but none of it returns me a list of unique names.
What's the best way to do this?  I've thought about creating a custom filter, but wondering if there is a better way to do it.

I've got a dictionary It looks like you actually have a list of dictionaries, but it's unclear because your example is incomplete.

Please add a minimal reproducible example so others can more precisely identify the source of your error.

From the docs:

Returns a list of unique items from the given iterable.
case_sensitive – Treat upper and lower case strings as distinct.
attribute – Filter objects with unique values for this attribute.

Because you want to eliminate duplicates based on the value of the name argument, you should set the attribute argument accordingly:
{% for name in data | unique(attribute="name") %}


I assume that data is a list containing many dictionaries which include the above three as well.  The following will work if you want dicts in which the value of the key 'name' is unique.
I have little knowledge in jinja2 as I do most of the things in flask itself. Why should we not do in this way which gives the similar result?
python file(flask):
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

data = [{
            'id': 16, 
            'name': 'something', 
            'client': 'client1', 
        }, 

      {
            'id': 17, 
            'name': 'something', 
            'client': 'client2', 
        },
      {
            'id': 18, 
            'name': 'something-else', 
        'client': 'client3', 
      },
      {
            'id': 19, 
            'name': 'One more', 
        'client': 'client4', 
      }
      ]
      
result = []
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    sub = data[:i] + data[i+1:]    
    ls = [y['name'] for y in sub]
    if x['name'] not in ls: result.append(x)


      
@app.route('/')
def provide_dict():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', data = result)
      
if __name__ == '__main__': app.run()   

    

JINJA2:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>

        <table>
            {% for x in data %}     
                
                {% for key, value in x.items() %}
                            <tr>
                                <th> {{ key }} </th>
                                <td> {{ value }} </td>
                            </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                    
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>

Output:


The question was how to do this in a jinja template, not in regular python code.

@JohnGordon, Now I got it and given another solution.

@JohnGordon, There was an error when I posted 11 hours back. So deleted. Now corrected the error, tested and reposted. Check my edited answer.

@SuramuthuR I guess a better question to help me learn would be, why would I want to do it like that?  I mean the jinja filter is built-in, clean, simple, and easy for future maintainers of this code to know what it's doing.  Since the data is already being used in the template in other ways, you're also proposing sending a whole new partially duplicated data set.  Help me understand why this approach would be better?

@supergper, It's just because: I can use only the resources which I had learned already. I don't need to learn jinja2 template's syntax completely,  having known python and flask. (In fact I know only little bit of jinja2 template logics. Rest I could do with python)
